# On click of the Button I want Fragment 1 layout to be replaced with Fragment 2 layout but its throwing: java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: android, kotlin, android-activity, fragment, communication

**First Fragment's code**

```
class MainFragment : Fragment() {

override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    val mainInflater = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false)
    return mainInflater
}

fun thisdata():String{

    return "Hello from MainFragment"
}

}
```

**First Fragment XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainFragment">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etSavedData"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
        android:hint="Enter the Text"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnSaveData"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="120dp"
        android:text="Save"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Main Activity's code**

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    //Set replace Main Activity content with the Fragment1 content
    val mainFragment = MainFragment()

    supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().add(R.id.contain_fragment, mainFragment).commit()
    val thedata = mainFragment.thisdata()
    Log.e("Main Frag to Activity", thedata)

    btnSaveData.setOnClickListener { 

        val secondFragment = SecondFragment()
        supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().add(R.id.contain_fragment, secondFragment).commit()
    }

}

}
```

**Main Activity XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/contain_fragment"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


</RelativeLayout>
```

**Second Fragment's code**

```
class SecondFragment : Fragment() {

override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    val secondInflater = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_second, container, false)
    return secondInflater
}

}
```

**Second Fragment XML**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
    tools:context=".SecondFragment">

    <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvDisplayText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        tools:text="Text displayed here." />

</FrameLayout>
```

**Following Exception showing up in Logcat**

> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual
>   method 'void
>   android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)'
>   on a null object reference
>           at com.example.demo2.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:22)*

Comment: Please also post xml of activity. It might be due to the wrong id of the button. So, share xml also for better understanding.

Comment: I think it's not the full XML. Is it full XML of MainActivity?

Comment: I've edit the whole query to make it easier for everyone to see.

Comment: If `btnSaveData` is to be in `MainFragment`, then you should be handling it in `MainFragment`, not in `MainActivity`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Thanks Tash, that actually make sense, unfortunately it was still showing the same exception but I finally manage to resolve the issue by doing the following. **

```
    class MainFragment : Fragment() {

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        val mainInflater = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false)
         mainInflater.btnSaveData.setOnClickListener {

        val secondFragment = SecondFragment()

            secondFragment?.let {
                 activity?.supportFragmentManager?.beginTransaction()?.replace(R.id.contain_fragment, secondFragment)?.commit()
             }

            }
        return mainInflater
    }

    fun thisdata():String{

        return "Hello from MainFragment"
    }

}
```

Comment: Glad to have helped. I had assumed you were using Kotlin Android extensions (ktx). You can accept your own answer then.

Answer (score 0):

You either need to move your `btnSaveData` button into the MainActivity, or you should move the onClickListener into the `MainFragment`, along with some other changes. Something like:

```
class MainFragment : Fragment() {

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
          // Inflate the layout for this fragment
         val mainInflater = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false)
    btnSaveData.setOnClickListener { 

         val secondFragment = SecondFragment()
         activity.supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().add(R.id.contain_fragment, secondFragment).commit()
        }
        return mainInflater
    }

    fun thisdata():String{

        return "Hello from MainFragment"
    }

}
```